# $V_\lambda$ models axioms of set theory

Tags: set-theory

I have to prove that for a limit ordinal $\lambda$
$$V_\lambda \models \Phi $$
where $\Phi$ is the Intersection Axiom, the Union Axiom, the Axiom of Choice or the Power Set Axiom. Where $V$ is the cumulative hierarchy.

I am stuck on this one, do not know where to begin.

Comment: What is the intersection axiom?

Answer (score 2):

I'll prove two of these to give you a feel for how this works.

**Union**

To show that this axiom is true, we have to show that $V_\lambda\vDash \forall x, \exists y, \forall z(z \in y \iff \exists w(w \in x \land z \in x)$ ie. for all $x \in V_\lambda$ we must find $y \in V_\lambda$ such that for all $z \in V_\lambda, z \in y$ if and only if there exists $w \in V_\lambda$ such that $z \in w$ and $w \in x$.

So let $x \in V_\lambda$, we'll show that $\bigcup x$ works just fine, first note that $\rho(x) < \lambda$ and so there exists $\beta < \lambda$ such that $x \in V_\beta$ and so $\bigcup x \in V_{\beta + 1} \subset V_\lambda$.

Now suppose $z \in V_\lambda$. Then if $z \in \bigcup x$ we have $z \in w$ for some $w \in z$, but $w \in V_\lambda$ so the forwards direction of the biconditional holds. Similarly if there exists $w \in V_\lambda$ such that $w \in x$ and $z \in w$ then $z \in \bigcup X$.

Hence $V_\lambda\vDash \textrm{The Union Axiom}$

**Powerset Axiom**

We want to show $V_\lambda\forall x, \exists y, \forall z (z \in y \iff z \subset x)$ and like before these means that forall $x \in V_\lambda$ we must find $y \in V_\lambda$ which acts like the powerset (within $V_\lambda$).

So let $x \in V_\lambda$, again we claim $\mathcal{P}(x)$ will work just fine. Since $x \in V_\beta$ for some $\beta < \lambda$ we also have that all elements of $x$ are in $V_\beta$ and so $\mathcal{P}(x) \subset V_{\beta + 1}$ and so $\mathcal{P}(x) \in V_{\beta + 2} \subset V_\lambda$. At this point it's routine to check the remaining things to show that $V_\lambda\vDash \textrm{Powerset Axiom}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $A$ be any nonempty set of rank $\alpha$. Then the transitive closure of $A$ also has rank $\alpha$. Now, every one of the following is a subset of the transitive closure:

1. $\bigcup A$,
2. $\bigcap A$,
3. any transversal of $A$,
4. any member of $\mathcal P(A)$.

In the same way, you can show that every $V_\lambda$ satisfies all axioms of ZFC except possibly (some instances of) replacement, provided $V$ itself satisfies these axioms.